# Add individual <hx> tag to widget title in sidebar

Tags: widgets, sidebar

In my sidebar every widget title is enclosed in `<h2>` tags.

I use 4 widgets in my sidebar and I'd like to have the first 2 widget titles as `<h2>` and the other 2 as `<h4>`.

I changed in my function.php as given below:

```
'before_title' => '<h4>', 
'after_title' => '</h4>',
```

but that changes all titles.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic_sidebar_params` is the filter that lets you modify those parameters on a per-widget basis. It fires for every sidebar though, so you'll need to use both `add_action` & `remove_action` call. Try `var_dump` once before writing the code to get an idea of what you have to do

### ADDED AN EXAMPLE ON REQUEST

This example adds an extra class to each widget depending on the order in which they appear i.e. first widget  will have class "widget-1", 2nd will have "widget-2" & so on

```
function add_first_last_class_to_widget($params) {
    STATIC $widget_num = array();
    $this_id = $params[0]['id'];
    $arr_registered_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets();
    if (!isset($arr_registered_widgets[$this_id]) || !is_array($arr_registered_widgets[$this_id]))
        return $params;

    if (isset($widget_num[$this_id]))
        $widget_num[$this_id]++;
    else
        $widget_num[$this_id] = 1;
    $class = 'class="widget-' . $widget_num[$this_id] . ' ';

    $params[0]['before_widget'] = str_replace('class="', $class, $params[0]['before_widget']);

    return $params;
}
```

Comment: I didn't find proper example for this  `dynamic_sidebar_params`.
How to use this I don't understand is it possible to give one small example. I'm new in wordpress.

Comment: edited the answer :)